# checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener call crashes app?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-2.3

I have this simple code but I can't figure for the life of me why it crashes the app.

```
package com.leonnears.android.andAnother;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

public class AndAnotherActivity extends Activity
{
    CheckBox dahBox;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dahBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.someCheck);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        dahBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {   
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    dahBox.setText("This checkbox is: checked");
                }else
                {
                    dahBox.setText("This checkbox is: unchecked");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have done tests and commented parts of code nad it looks like the call to `dahBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener()` is crashing my program. At one point, I ended up doing this:

```
dahBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
```

To see if the crash could be there for some reason, aaand it looks like it was.

Can someone help me with this? I will highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dahBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.someCheck);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

rearrange the statement to

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dahBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.someCheck);
```

you have to set view first then use its resources

Comment: Yeah I JUST found that and was answering my own question! Haha I feel dumb. Thanks a lot for your reply, I will mark yours as checked rather than me posting my own.